# Get detail of all IDs in comma separated string of same table, MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Consider the table,

```
id   username    co_manager    privilege
1    user_1      0             NULL
2    user_2      1             4,5
3    user_3      1             6
4    user_4      0             NULL
5    user_5      0             NULL
6    user_6      0             NULL
```

Here the column **privilege** is user IDs managed by **co_manager**. If am getting an input user ID as 2, then I should get an output like this,

```
id   username    co_manager    privilege
2    user_2      1             4,5
4    user_4      0             NULL
5    user_5      0             NULL
```

For this I used a query like this,

```
select * from users WHERE id = 2 OR FIND_IN_SET(id,privilege);
```

but not getting the required output.

I have tried the sample here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c8c35

Thanks

Comment: Normalize your data. Do not use comma-separated lists ever

Comment: I think you should normalize your data... it's not correct and prone to difficulites and error to set up a one-to-many relation like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, normalize the DB. Create a new table user_privilege and have a foreign key relation with users table.

But then, with the current scenario you can try the following query.

```
select * from users WHERE id = 2 OR 
FIND_IN_SET(id,(select privilege from users where id = 2));
```